# Dockerizing ambry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi Im trying to run [ambry](https://github.com/linkedin/ambry) in docker

part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
ambry:
    build: resources/ambry
```

and Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:latest

USER root

RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk upgrade && \
  apk add git && \
  apk add bash && \
  apk add openjdk8 && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk

WORKDIR /tmp

CMD ["sh"]

RUN git clone https://github.com/linkedin/ambry.git

WORKDIR ambry

RUN ./gradlew allJar

WORKDIR target

CMD mkdir logs

CMD java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../config/log4j.properties -jar ambry.jar --serverPropsFilePath ../config/server.properties --hardwareLayoutFilePath ../config/HardwareLayout.json --partitionLayoutFilePath ../config/PartitionLayout.json > logs/server.log &

CMD java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../config/log4j.properties -cp "*" com.github.ambry.frontend.AmbryFrontendMain --serverPropsFilePath ../config/frontend.properties --hardwareLayoutFilePath ../config/HardwareLayout.json --partitionLayoutFilePath ../config/PartitionLayout.json > logs/frontend.log &
```

I was doing those commands in shell , which are taken from https://github.com/linkedin/ambry. And works fine but docker on start just exit..:

```
dockerized_ambry_1 exited with code 0
```

Any one know why it exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

> There can only be one `CMD` instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one `CMD` then only the last `CMD` will take effect.

Looks like the only `CMD` of yours that actually runs is "run the Java class `com.github.ambry.frontend.AmbryFrontendMain`". But you launch this as a background process (you specified `&`).

The container lifetime is tied to "launch background task", which completes immediately. Thus the container exits immediately.

---

Since your container is responsible for launching *two* services (`ambry.jar`, `com.github.ambry.frontend.AmbryFrontendMain`): you will want the container lifetime to be tied to *both* of those, and you will want any SIGTERM sent to the container, to elegantly shutdown *both* of those.

I recommend using an *init system* to start & end those services. [Alpine Linux typically uses OpenRC](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System), but IIRC the *Dockerized Alpine Linux* does **not** have any init system, so you would need to find a variant that does (or install it yourself).

Personally I've found that it's non-trivial to use init systems with Docker: the most common problem is that logs don't go to the container's stdout; until you overcome that, it can be a black box. Good luck!

Comment: do you know how to do this on other image ? I dont really need to stick with alpine:latest

Comment: Find a base image which has alpine plus some init system (e.g. openrc, runit, supervisor). Here's [one that uses `runit`](https://github.com/QuantumObject/docker-alpine). your Dockerfile should have `CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]` (or maybe just remove all CMD lines, so you can inherit the one from your base image). See the "Adding additional daemons" section in those instructions. you have two daemons to create. make service folders to hold their run scripts, `RUN mkdir -p /etc/service/ambry /etc/service/ambry-frontend`. use `ADD` to create `/etc/service/ambry/run`, `/etc/service/ambry-frontend/run`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM quantumobject/docker-alpine

USER root

RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk upgrade && \
  apk add git && \
  apk add bash && \
  apk add openjdk8 && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk

RUN git clone https://github.com/linkedin/ambry.git

WORKDIR ambry/target

RUN cd .. && ./gradlew allJar

RUN mkdir logs

RUN java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../config/log4j.properties -jar ambry.jar --serverPropsFilePath ../config/server.properties --hardwareLayoutFilePath ../config/HardwareLayout.json --partitionLayoutFilePath ../config/PartitionLayout.json > logs/server.log && /sbin/my_init &

CMD java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../config/log4j.properties -cp "*" com.github.ambry.frontend.AmbryFrontendMain --serverPropsFilePath ../config/frontend.properties --hardwareLayoutFilePath ../config/HardwareLayout.json --partitionLayoutFilePath ../config/PartitionLayout.json > logs/frontend.log && /sbin/my_init
```

does the job :) thanks [birchlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5257399/birchlabs)

Comment: that's working for the wrong reason. your `CMD` command is no longer a background task (you removed the `&`), so the container's lifetime is tied to its execution. I suspect that the `&& /sbin/my_init` doesn't do anything meaningful. you're not actually using the init system in any way (i.e. you could do this much with just the standard alpine base image). your services aren't launched/closed by runit, so you still have the problem of "terminating with Ctrl C will not shutdown both processes gracefully". this means you could lose data whenever you terminate this container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete working solution:

https://github.com/maciejbak85/ambry-docker